# Still Stopping User Manager for UID 121... After remove nvidia-driver*

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'd like to install nvidia-driver-390.
The following is my step...

1. apt install nvidia-driver-390
2. Occur boot problem (Stopping User Manager for UID 121...)
3. apt remove --purge nvidia-driver* on Recovery Mode
4. I downloaded nvidia-driver-390.run  and sudo bash it.
5. Occur boot problem (Stopping User Manager for UID 121...)
6. apt remove --purge nvidia-driver* on Recovery Mode
7. Still Occur boot problem (Stopping User Manager for UID 121...)

Comment: You've provided no OS/product/release details; nor details of your hardware?  Did you try installing with `ubuntu-drivers` ?

Comment: OS : ubuntu18.04 
product: Quadro P2000
Yes I checked that nvidia-driver-390 is available by ubuntu-drivers